# ATG Connection Threads

Tags: mysql, repository, atg

I am facing an issue where I am getting the following error:

```
CONTAINER:atg.repositoryException; SOURCE:java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMFAIL start() failed on resource'ATGProductionDS_atg11':XAResource.XAER_RMFAIL: Resource manager is unavailable.
```

How do I solve this?

1. Do ATG connection threads get closed implicitly or do we have to close it explicitly?
2. Do ATG connection threads get closed after updateItem() and addItem() methods implicitly?
3. How can we close an ATG session thread explicitly?

Comment: If you are using the `Repository` Layer you do not need to explicitly close the connection. This is done via the `Repository`. Do you have any connections that do not go via the `Repository`? Are you trying to use more connections in your connection pool than what is available in the resource configuration on your database?

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially a number of causes for this issue.  There is a [support document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2008232.1) in Oracle support portal which helps understand where the issue is (You will have to register for Oracle Support access)

1. Slow running query which is never timing out due to a misconfiguration
2. The timeouts for your datasource(s) are not setup correctly between WebLogic and the ATG application